# Converting Numbers to Local (UTF8) Bengali numbers

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am trying to convert the English numbers (1, 2, 3) to Bengali numbers (১, ২, ৩).

For example, if I get 10000, then I want to show like ১০,০০০.

I can replace the number one by one with the Bengali counterpart using `replaceAll` method

But I want to know if there is an alternative solution to do that instead of the above.

Comment: obviously it would be better to do it in one iteration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used [NumberFormat](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/intl/NumberFormat-class.html) from popular library [Intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) and converted it easily like below

```
NumberFormat("##,##,##,###", "bn").format(10000)
```

And the **output** is:

```
১০,০০০
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
val convertedString = String.format(Locale.forLanguageTag("bn"), "%d", 1234567890)
```